# uniformly convergent implies uniformly equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

We set 
$$C(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: f \text{ is continuous and } \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|f(x) \right| < +\infty \right\}, $$
and assume that $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $C(\mathbb{R})$ that converges uniformly to $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$. 
Then it can be shown that $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is pointwise equicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$,
there exists $\delta >0$ (depending on $x$ and $\varepsilon$) such that, for all $n \geq 1$ and $\left| y-x \right| < \delta,$ we have $\left| f_{n}(y) - f_{n}(y)\right| < \varepsilon.$

My question is: In this setting, is it true that $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$? In other words,  for every  $\varepsilon > 0$,
there exists $\delta >0$ (depending only on $\varepsilon$) such that, for all $n \geq 1$ and $\left| y-x \right| < \delta,$ we have $\left| f_{n}(y) - f_{n}(y)\right| < \varepsilon.$

This is not my homework. In fact, I am just curious about the result when reading books on Real Analysis, and I think the answer is negative but cannot find any counterexamples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Globally uniformly, or uniformly on compacts? Globally uniform convergence is an extremely restrictive assumption. On a compact domain your result is actually true, and any good proof of Arzela-Ascoli should show this.

Comment: I meant "globally uniformly." I agree with your point. The answer is positive on compact sets, I am just curious about the conclusion on the whole space.

Comment: $C(\mathbb R)$ is not good notation for that space, as that is usually reserved for the space of all continuous functions on $\mathbb R.$ $C_b(\mathbb R),$ where $b$ stands for "bounded", is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Find a bounded continuous $f$ on $\mathbb R$ that is not uniformly continuous. Then definee $f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $n.$